# I wrote a program to divide and array into two new arrays but for some reason, the elements of the original array is changing. C++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, mergesort, divide

I don't understand why my original array i.e. arr[] changing (changing as in the order of number is changing, the last four elements are becoming the first four), Please explain why is that happening even when I have not assigned it anywhere.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int arr[] {5,4,1,8,7,2,6,3};
    int numberOfElements=8; //sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])
    int array1[]{};
    int array2[]{};
    for(int i=0;i<=(numberOfElements/2)-1;i++){
        array1[i]=arr[i];
        array2[i]=arr[i+4];
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int array1[]{};` -- What does this line do?  What is your intention here?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I wrote that to declare a new array

Comment: What C++ book are you following that declares arrays with no size denoted?  That syntax is not valid, and even it was valid, what tells the compiler to make the array hold `8` values?  Arrays in C++ must have their size specified by a compile-time expression.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie OK yeah I see the mistake now, I was used to using vectors so I forgot to declare its size.

Comment: But even with vectors, you must size them appropriately either by constructing them with a size argument, or calling `push_back`, `emplace_back`, `resize`, or `insert`.  Your code would have failed for vectors also.

Comment: Vectors cannot read your mind too ;). For fixed size array you can use `std::array<int,8>`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ok I will keep that in mind, Thanks.

Comment: when you are using gcc I strongly suggest you to use `-Wall -Werror -pedantic`, it helps to spot many mistakes and to disable weird extensions that one should only use when you know what they are doing. Other compilers have similar settings to make your code fail to compile: https://godbolt.org/z/Ye14axsx4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called Undefined Behavior.
You accidently rewriting memory which not allocated for you arrays

```
array1[i]=arr[i];
array2[i]=arr[i+4];
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int arr[] {5,4,1,8,7,2,6,3};
    int numberOfElements=8;
    int array1[]{};
    int array2[]{};
    int i=0;
    while(i<numberOfElements){
            cout << arr[0];
            if(i > 3){
                array2[i]=arr[i];
            }else{
                array1[i]=arr[i];
            }
            i++;
        }
    return 0;
}
```